# ActiveRecord with MySQL-Adapter: really slow INSERTs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

A Rails 2 application has been upgraded to Rails 3.2.11. Everything runs just fine, except for one thing:

In production mode on two different servers with brand new hardware, MySQL INSERTs from **within** the Rails app are very slow, typically they take around 100ms, while only 1ms when queried directly from the MySQL console. On my development machine (slightly aged iMac with Mac OS X 10.7) these queries are always fast - from within the Rails app or from the MySQL console.

I have already tried different /etc/my.cnf configurations (including the Ubuntu default), an older version of Rails (3.2.6) and the mysql gem (0.3.10) It also makes no difference if the INSERT action is executed as MyObject.create or ActiveRecord::Base.connection.insert_sql("INSERT into my_objects ... ")

This is the production environment:

New Intel Xeon hardware with 16GB Ram and 2x1000GB HD

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-35-generic x86_64)

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Rails 3.2.11

mysql2 0.3.11 gem